# How to implement onClick in RecyclerView Adapter with databinding using Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, adapter, android-databinding

I created a RecyclerView Adapter using databinding and I'm trying to handle Click events inside this adapter but I don't know exactly how. I found different topics but couldn't solve my problem yet. Thanks!
Where should I implement (inside the Adapter class) the onClick function?

**Adapter Class**

```
class RemovableContactsAdapter(val viewModel: GroupDetailsViewModel,val callback:GroupContactsCallback) : RecyclerView.Adapter<RemovableContactsViewHolder>() {
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RemovableContactsViewHolder {
    val binding: ViewDataBinding =
        DataBindingUtil.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), viewType, parent, false)
    return RemovableContactsViewHolder(binding)
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RemovableContactsViewHolder, position: Int) {
    holder.bind(viewModel, callback, position)

}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return viewModel.currentGroup.value?.contacts?.size ?: 0
}

override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
    return R.layout.removable_contact_layout
}
}

class RemovableContactsViewHolder(val binding: ViewDataBinding) :
RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {

fun bind(viewModel: GroupDetailsViewModel, callback: GroupContactsCallback, position: Int) {
    binding.root.selected_contact_iv.apply {
        visibility = if (viewModel.currentGroup.value?.contacts!![position].selected) {
            View.VISIBLE
        } else {
            View.GONE
        }
    }
    binding.setVariable(BR.contact, viewModel.currentGroup.value?.contacts?.get(position))
    binding.setVariable(BR.callback, callback)
    binding.executePendingBindings()
   }
}
```

Callback interface in Fragment class:

```
interface GroupContactsCallback {
   fun selectContact(contact: ContactModel)
}
```

***EDIT***

I updated the bind function inside RemovableContactsViewHolder but still not working.

```
class RemovableContactsViewHolder(val binding: ViewDataBinding) :
RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {

fun bind(viewModel: GroupDetailsViewModel, callback: GroupContactsCallback, position: Int) {
    itemView.setOnClickListener {
        viewModel.currentGroup.value?.contacts?.get(position)!!.selected = !viewModel.currentGroup.value?.contacts?.get(position)!!.selected
        callback.selectContact(viewModel.currentGroup.value?.contacts?.get(position)!!)
    }

    binding.root.selected_contact_iv.apply {
        visibility = if (viewModel.currentGroup.value?.contacts!![position].selected) {
            View.VISIBLE
        } else {
            View.GONE
        }
    }

    binding.setVariable(BR.contact, viewModel.currentGroup.value?.contacts?.get(position))
    binding.setVariable(BR.callback, callback)
    binding.executePendingBindings()
}
```

Comment: Seems like very common question, check this out https://medium.com/android-gate/recyclerview-item-click-listener-the-right-way-daecc838fbb9

Comment: I read the article and added onClickListener inside the bind function From ViewHolder class but still not working. I updated the question, please take a look. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not a good practice to handle click inside your adapter. And don't use interface just for this. Use this instead.

```
class YourRecyclerViewAdapter(private val onSelect: (YourDataType?) -> Unit) : RecyclerView.Adapter<YourRecyclerViewAdapter.YourViewHolder>() {

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: YourViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bind(getItem(position), onSelect)
    }

    class ViewHolder(private val binding: YourViewBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {

        fun bind(yourDataType: YourDataType?, onSelect: (YourDataType?) -> Unit) {

           // bind your view here
           binding.root.setOnClickListener {
               onSelect(yourDataType)
           }
        }
    }
}
```

In your Fragment/Activity

```
// Set this adapter to your recycler view
val adapter = YourRecyclerViewAdapter { yourDataType-> 
    // Handle click here
}
```

Comment: Good answer, but I would also add an explanation for why handling click inside an adapter is bad practice

Comment: I have that callback as parameter for Adapter, wouldn't be better to use that? Thanks

Comment: Well, it breaks the "Separation of concern" concept. The adapter concern is just to act as a bridge b/w our data and the recyclerview not to handle click. Passing it back to fragment/activity restores that. Second, using callbacks may leads to Memory leaks as it going to have the reference to the fragment/activity.

Comment: @Razvan22 callback is not ideal. We can obviously use it but memory leaks could happen. And this is also a very clean way to handle the clicks.

Answer (score 0):

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RemovableContactsViewHolder, position: Int) {
holder.bind(viewModel, callback, position)

holder.binding.your_view_like_button.setOnClickListener {
// do something 
}
}
```

- > for example

  ```
    class AppointTimeSloatAdapter(
        private var mOptionList: List<String>,
        var context: Context,
        var appointmentDate: String,
    ) : RecyclerView.Adapter<AppointTimeSloatAdapter.ViewHolder>() {
        private var checkedRadioButton: CompoundButton? = null

        override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
            val viewProductCategoryBinding: AdapterAppointmentTimeSloteBinding =
                AdapterAppointmentTimeSloteBinding.inflate(
                    LayoutInflater.from(parent.context),
                    parent,
                    false
                )
            return ViewHolder(viewProductCategoryBinding)
        }


        override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
            val option = getItem(position)
            holder.binding.radioBtn.text = option.toString()

            holder.binding.radioBtn.setOnCheckedChangeListener(checkedChangeListener)
            if (holder.binding.radioBtn.isChecked) checkedRadioButton = holder.binding.radioBtn

            holder.binding.radioBtn.setOnClickListener {
                var intent = Intent(context, NewAppointmentActivity::class.java)
                intent.putExtra("time",holder.binding.radioBtn.text.toString())
                intent.putExtra("appointmentDate", appointmentDate)
                context.startActivity(intent)
            }


        }

        private val checkedChangeListener =
            CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener { compoundButton, isChecked ->
                checkedRadioButton?.apply { setChecked(!isChecked) }
                checkedRadioButton = compoundButton.apply { setChecked(isChecked) }
            }

        fun updateList(list: ArrayList<String>) {
            mOptionList = list
            notifyDataSetChanged()
        }


        private fun getItem(index: Int): String {
            return mOptionList[index]
        }

        override fun getItemCount(): Int {
            return mOptionList.size
        }


        inner class ViewHolder(val binding: AdapterAppointmentTimeSloteBinding) :
            RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root), View.OnClickListener {
            override fun onClick(v: View?) {
                ////
            }
        }

    }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Apply following approach.

In Your adapter class

```
class RemovableContactsAdapter(val viewModel: GroupDetailsViewModel,val callback:GroupContactsCallback) : RecyclerView.Adapter<RemovableContactsViewHolder>() {
private var onClickListener: OnClickListener?=null
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RemovableContactsViewHolder {
    val binding: ViewDataBinding =
        DataBindingUtil.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), viewType, parent, false)
    return RemovableContactsViewHolder(binding)
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RemovableContactsViewHolder, position: Int) {
    holder.bind(viewModel, callback, position)

holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
            if(onClickListener!=null){
                onClickListener!!.onClick(position)
            }
        }

}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return viewModel.currentGroup.value?.contacts?.size ?: 0
}

override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
    return R.layout.removable_contact_layout
}
}

class RemovableContactsViewHolder(val binding: ViewDataBinding) :
RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {

fun bind(viewModel: GroupDetailsViewModel, callback: GroupContactsCallback, position: Int) {
    binding.root.selected_contact_iv.apply {
        visibility = if (viewModel.currentGroup.value?.contacts!![position].selected) {
            View.VISIBLE
        } else {
            View.GONE
        }
    }
    binding.setVariable(BR.contact, viewModel.currentGroup.value?.contacts?.get(position))
    binding.setVariable(BR.callback, callback)
    binding.executePendingBindings()
   }

 fun setOnClickListener(onClickListener: OnClickListener){
        this.onClickListener=onClickListener
    }

    interface OnClickListener{
        fun onClick(position: Int)
    }
}
```

In you Activity/Fragment class create an object named adapter and then

```
val adapter=RemovableContactsAdapter(viewModel,callback)
adapter.setOnClickListener(object :SettingAdapter.OnClickListener{
            override fun onClick(position: Int){
                //position is your clicked view position
            }
        })
```

I have modified your code in my answer go for it hope problem will be solved.