# RecyclerView onClickListener with DiffUtil

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

How is it possible to handle onClick for RecyclerView with DiffUtil callback? And how can I change background color for chosen item in recyclerview? I have two RecyclerViews in one Activity. When user click on item in RecyclerView A, something happen in RecyclerView B.

This is the class

```
import androidx.room.ColumnInfo

data class SkladTuple(
    @ColumnInfo(name = "sklad") val sklad: Int?,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "reg") val reg: Int?
)
```

This is adapter:

```
class SkladAdapter: ListAdapter<SkladTuple, SkladAdapter.PolozkaViewHolder>(DiffCallback())
{
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): PolozkaViewHolder {
        val binding = SkladyItemBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false)
        return PolozkaViewHolder(binding)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: PolozkaViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val currentItem = getItem(position)
        holder.bind(currentItem)  

    }
    class PolozkaViewHolder(private val binding: SkladyItemBinding): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root){
        fun bind(polozkaSklad: SkladTuple){
            binding.apply {
                tvSklad.text = polozkaSklad.sklad.toString()
                tvRegal.text = polozkaSklad.reg.toString()

            }
        }
    }
    class DiffCallback: DiffUtil.ItemCallback<SkladTuple>(){
        override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: SkladTuple, newItem: SkladTuple) =
            oldItem.sklad == newItem.sklad

        override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: SkladTuple, newItem: SkladTuple) =
            oldItem == newItem
    }
}
```

This is the Activity

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class DokladActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private val skladViewModel: SkladViewModel by viewModels()
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        val binding = ActivityDokladBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)
        binding.btVybratDoklad.setOnClickListener{
            openActivity(binding.root)
        }
        val skladAdapter = SkladAdapter()
        val dokladAdapter = DokladAdapter()
        binding.apply {
            recyclerViewSklady.apply {
                adapter = skladAdapter

                layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this@DokladActivity)
            }
            skladViewModel.skladyPolozky.observe(this@DokladActivity) {
                skladAdapter.submitList(it)
                Log.d("Doklad", skladAdapter.currentList.toString())
            }

            recyclerViewDoklady.apply {
                adapter = dokladAdapter
                layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this@DokladActivity)
            }
            skladViewModel.dokladyPolozky.observe(this@DokladActivity){
                dokladAdapter.submitList(it)
                Log.d("Doklad", dokladAdapter.currentList.toString())
            }
        }


    }

    fun openActivity(view: View){
        val intent = Intent(this,PolozkaActivity::class.java )
        startActivity(intent)
    }
}
```

This is ViewModel

```
@HiltViewModel
class SkladViewModel @Inject constructor(
    repository: SybaseRepository
): ViewModel(){
    val skladyPolozky = repository.getAllSkladFromPolozka().asLiveData()
    val dokladyPolozky = repository.getAllHlavickyToDoklad().asLiveData()
}
```

This is layout - I have two recyclerviews. When user click on item in recyclerview A, something happen in recyclerview B

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline8"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.02" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline9"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.7" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline10"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.25" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline11"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.75" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline12"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.9" />

    <TableLayout
        android:stretchColumns="1,2"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline10"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline9"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline8">

        <TableRow>
            <TextView
                android:text="SKLAD"
                android:textSize="16dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_column="1"/>
            <TextView
                android:text="REGAL"
                android:textSize="16dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_column="1"/>
        </TableRow>

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/recycler_view_sklady"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            tools:listitem="@layout/sklady_item"
            />

    </TableLayout>

<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:stretchColumns="1,2,3,4,5"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline11"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline10"
    >
    <TableRow>
        <TextView
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="U"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="DOKL"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="ODB"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="ORG"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="DATUM"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </TableRow>


    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

        android:id="@+id/recycler_view_doklady"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:listitem="@layout/doklady_item"/>
</TableLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bt_back"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:text="Zpět"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline12" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bt_vybrat_doklad"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
        android:text="Vybrat doklad"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline12" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="209dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline12"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline9"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline11" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How is it possible to ...

You have a ViewModel and it exposes two observable liveData with the List that your RecyclerViews need (two adapters, two lists).

The logic to decide that List A, Item 1 was tapped, and therefore List B, Item N has to change its background is absolutely *outside* of the scope of the Recycler View, Adapter, Activity, and possibly even ViewModel.

Ultimately, when a data mutation occurs (you tapped Item 1), you receive this event, **act upon it** (aka: send it to the Viewmodel -> Repository -> transform the data -> publish new lists(s) with the mutated data.

Eventually, your ViewModel will receive the new data from the repository, and will update the LiveData(s) that your activity is observing, and this will result in the adapters being submitted new data, that your DiffUtils will pick up, causing the Adapter to re-bind the modified views.

#### UPDATE

Based on the question/answer you linked, and your comment, I think this deserves a further comment.

1. The person says: "it's not a good idea to handle click on the adapter, nor to use an interface", then proceeds to "handle" the click, *and* uses an anonymous function (so it could have been an interface for the purposes of testing, but it instead made it a "higher order function".
2. This is exactly the same principle I was describing, only an interface is easier to understand.

Think about the responsibilities like this:

ViewHolder: It knows nothing about the data, recycler view, adapter, etc. But it has direct access to each "row/column" of your List. It owns the views, and it can manipulate them based on the data it's supplied and told to "hold" alongside the needed views. It doesn't create the views (it's told to) but it has them. All this can do in regards of clicking, is to make either expose a view (so a click listener can be set by someone externally) or simply delegate it.

Adapter: It knows nothing about the views other than their type (if used) and how to create viewHolders and "bind" them. So it sits in between, but it does have access to the data source provided to it (the list you supply) and it does have access to each "view holder" that it created; it knows more or less what's on screen, and can map a position to the data.

RecyclerView/Fragment/ViewModel: these have no idea what happens inside an adapter (nor they should), but they are primarily interested in when a click (or event) happened so they can presumably do something about it.

Based on all this, let's look at [this person's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67054751/how-to-implement-onclick-in-recyclerview-adapter-with-databinding-using-kotlin) (vs. what I was suggesting):

1. The Adapter's constructor is modified to receive a function:

`(private val onSelect: (YourDataType?) -> Unit)`

I normally define an interface:

```
interface SomethingClickListener {
  fun onSomethingICaredForHappened(something: Something)
}
```

And pass it along to my adapter, but the idea is the same; I prefer the interface because it's easier to use Dependency Injection with concrete types (and easier to test), but it's just a personal preference I believe.

`class YourAdapter(private val clickListener: SomethingClickListener)`

2. What happens inside the adapter is the same principle. You need to set the actual click listener on the views you expect to be clicked (or the whole itemView if you want the entire "row" to be clickable).

The linked answer gets away by simply using an anonymous implementation of a click listener and capturing the value sent to the bind method (it's fine), you could (or want to do more stuff in there). So you could use another interface or do that, essentially, the idea is the same, you're *passing the click event along*.

```
binding.root.setOnClickListener {
    onSelect(yourDataType)
  }
```

So it passes the `dataType` directly to the `onSelect` (which is the function supplied to the adapter). At this stage the only logic inside this is that you attach the "data" that was associated with the viewBinding that got clicked, that's the "one and only" information the adapter/viewholder can *and should* supply.

What happens after this `onSelect`, is that your fragment/activity receives this, and then you should call your ViewModel saying:

`viewModel.thisThingWasClicked(theThingYouReceived)`

And you get the idea...

I haven't updated it in a while (I think I wrote this 3 years ago in Java originally, then I naively converted it to Kt) except for updating libraries and making sure it still compiles, but you can see a "two interface approach" (kinda old school now with higher order functions being available via Kotlin), but still the same approach.

Take a look at this project (And specifically the [adapter](https://github.com/Gryzor/CheckBoxCounter/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/androidonlinux/checkboxcounter/ThingAdapter.kt).

Notice it accepts a `ThingClickListener`, but internally uses a `ToggleListener` to talk between ViewHolders and the Adapter.

In the end, this could be streamlined to use one less interface.

I hope this clarifies the idea.
Notice how neither the ViewHolder nor the Adapter have any responsibility beyond handling the Click listener and binding the correct data.

Comment: Eureka...I think I got it. Thanks a lot. Is it good practice to handle on click in the adapter or not. I am little bit confused. E.g. here it looks like it is possible both way. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67054751/how-to-implement-onclick-in-recyclerview-adapter-with-databinding-using-kotlin

Comment: Yes, Handling the click is "needed" somewhere, meaning, someone has to "set" a click listener in one or more views. But the responsibilities of what to do (and what to "pass along/bubble up") are different for each layer.